# tab host doesn't show all elements

Tags: android, android-xml

helllo, I try to create tab view there must be some elements in my case they are seekbar and horizontal linear layout with 2 textview, but it only shows element such is at the top.
Like in this image:

[image]

XML code of this tab:

```
                       <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tvTab2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            >
                        <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                            <TextView
                                    android:text="@string/bspa_count_of_hours"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            </TextView>
                            <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/bspa_count_of_hours_value"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            </TextView>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <SeekBar
                                android:id="@+id/bspa_seekbar_count_of_hours"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                />

                    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_height="match_parent"` should be `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` inner LinearLayout fill in parent.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tvTab2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="bspa_count_of_hours" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bspa_count_of_hours_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/bspa_seekbar_count_of_hours"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```